# Reformat certain paragraphs to Markdown

Tags: python, formatting, markdown, paragraph

I‘m a python beginner.

I have this code that get‘s all paragraphs after symbols ‘*****‘

```
import re

file = open('/Users/text.txt', mode='r')

result = [s.strip() for s in re.findall(r'^\*{4,}((?:\r?\n(?!\s*$|\*{4}).+)*)', file.read(), re.MULTILINE)]

print(*result, sep="\n\n")

file.close()
```

Current input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

****
Sed id placerat magna.

*******
*******
*******
Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique. 

Etiam dapibus faucibus gravida.
```

Current output:

```
Sed id placerat magna.

Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.
```

**Output needed:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

==Sed id placerat magna.==

==Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.==

Etiam dapibus faucibus gravida.
```

Basically trying to reformat highlights to Markdown .md format.
Got only so far but can‘t seem to figure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
import re

text = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

****
Sed id placerat magna.

*******
Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.

Etiam dapibus faucibus gravida.'''

print(re.sub(r'\n\*{4,}\n(.+)\n', r'\n==\1==\n', text))
```

There can be problems with start and end of the text, though. Probably it makes sense to add `\n` at start and at end before to process the text and remove them after. Just to be on the safe side.

**Update**

Here is the updated version to meet the new requirements:

```
import re

# open txt file
with open('d:/Users/text.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

text = re.sub('\*\n+\*', '**', text)  # remove all '\n' between all '*'
text = re.sub(r'\n\*{4,}\n(.+)\n', r'\n==\1==\n', text)

# save txt file
with open('d:/Users/output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

****
Sed id placerat magna.

*******
*******
*******
Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.

Etiam dapibus faucibus gravida.
```

Output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

==Sed id placerat magna.==

==Pellentesque in ex ac urna tincidunt tristique.==

Etiam dapibus faucibus gravida.
```

But actually to parse and reformat poorly formatted texts is always a quirk and basically endless task. I'm sure there will be another issues as well. You will always have only a partial temporary solution.

Comment: There are two issues that I still need to figure out: 1. the input is in the .txt folder since it‘s lot of text. I suppose this should work?: `file = open('/Users/text.txt', mode='r')` 2. My input formatting is awkward: some paragraphs have multiple `***` asterix paragraphs above — see edited question example.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much.